# jQuery : Selecting custom ul childrens

Tags: jquery, tags

ok, I have been through some basics but I'm not able to get this done. Problem is I don't want to specify id or class for any ul or li and if I click on a header included in the ul I want the li to be toggled (show/hide). How can I select the li under a header without specifying id and class???. Here is what I've tried :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <header>Menu 1</header>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <header>Menu 2</header>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <header>Menu 3</header>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('ul li').hide();
        $('ul header').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $('ul header').click(function(e) {
            $(this).next().toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ok. This one just toggles the last child of ul but no all of them. Any help would be appreciated, Thanx.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. `ul` elements can only contain `li` elements.

Comment: I didn't care much about html that's why I messed it up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [$.fn.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it will alternate between two functions when you click. Then, you want to use the [$.fn.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function to target all of the `li` elements with the same parent. [Here is a demo on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/dLhPX/)

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul header').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('ul header').toggle(function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').hide();
    });
});
```

**EDIT: my recommendations were confusing and conflicting when separate, so I will group them all together and explain**

1.) As Felix commented above, it is invalid HTML to have anything but `li` as a direct decendant of `ul`. So, you will need to change your markup to something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Menu 1</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

2.) I would set the following rules in your CSS, so that you don't have to do them with jQuery:

```
nav ul li { display: none; }
nav ul .header { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
```

So, with these two recommendations in place, your jQuery would now look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul .header').toggle(function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').hide();
    });
});
```

[Putting all of my recommendations together in a new fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/tsgPh/)

Comment: You beat me to it...deleting mine :)

Comment: @PhD haha I think we both had typos and bad code in ours too. we were just racing to get something up there!

Comment: but I can't understand something from your post. if header is li and all li are hidden how come I can click header to toggle the appearance?

Comment: @AliAhmed I had the `.header { display: block; cursor: pointer; }` rule in the jsfiddle, but not in the code I pasted in my answer. I corrected that and hopefully cleared everything up.

Comment: yeah the problem was I wanted to put some menus where the siblings are already hidden, but I got around it by using the css you posted above and using this jQuery code: '$('.header').siblings().hide();' . Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) gets the immediate following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) gets all the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul header').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('ul header').click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('li').toggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XeSbE/)